# Binding to a nested field of complex object and providing default value in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to providing default value when binding to complex object in AngularJs?

For example:

```
var myObj = {
  bacon: {
    calories: 9000,
    expire_date: '...'
  },
  meatball: {
    calories: 5000,
  },
};
```

And in the view:

```
<p>
  Bacon: {{myCtrl.myObj.bacon.calories}} kCal and expires on {{myCtrl.myObj.bacon.expire_date | date: 'medium'}}
</p>
<p>
  Meatball: {{myCtrl.myObj.meatball.calories}} kCal and expires on {{myCtrl.myObj.metaball.expire_date | date: 'medium'}}
</p>
<p>
  Egg: {{myCtrl.myObj.egg.calories}} kCal and expires on {{myCtrl.myObj.egg.expire_date | date: 'medium'}}
</p>
```

I don't have guarantee on the availability of bacon, meatball, egg, and their nested fields (the actual object will be requested from server).

How should I go about providing defaults without leaking undefined/NaN to user? (I already saw the `{{ A || B }}` syntax but because this is nested field so I'm not sure to make that work.)

Comment: FYI, if you wish to always have _default_ values to display to users, I'd recommend using Angular's [`constant`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#constant-recipe) provider (injectable like services) to keep track of values.

Comment: @miqid Okay, thanks. I was planning to embed this into template somewhere but will see what `constant` provider can give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular is really smart! It chooses to show nothing as opposed to NaN or undefined or null. You can go as many levels into a complex object without seeing these ugly strings.

Also, you can use the `ng-show="element_shown_if_expression_is_truthy"` directive or its compliment `ng-hide="expression"`

Also as a side note, `{{ A | B }}` does not use A or B if A is undefined. It actually puts A through the filter B which can do practically anything. There are many default filters and you can make your own. Check out [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Update: After re-reading your question, you really wanted a default value. You can use `angular.extend(dest, src)` to provide a default object and extend it with your server response. Check out [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

Comment: Thanks for all these options. I think this is all I need.I missed one pipe so actually I intended it to be `{{ A || B }}`. I'll definitely look into `angular.extend`. 

Retested my example again and I think I saw NaN earlier only because of some arithmetic operation involved, and because of a 'date' filter, e.g. `{{ terms.obj.test /1000 | date: 'medium'}}`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution here would be

```
{{ myCtrl.myObj.egg.calories || default_value }}
```

for each variable.

That being said, Joel's `angular.extend` solution will be the most *angulary* way of doing it (i.e. not putting data in your HTML).